# closed form solution for summation of  $\log(i)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Is there a way to find a closed form solution for:
(Note that base is $2$)

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\log_2(i)$

thanks for any help
Can't find a formula for this

Comment: Note that $\log a+\log b = \log (ab)$

Comment: Could we please change the index of summation here to something besides "$i$"?

Comment: @deoxygerbe What's wrong with $i$?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: It makes the question title ambiguous and confusing. Is the question about the power series for the logarithm of $i=\sqrt{-1}$? (which is what I thought when I first saw the question title)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \log i = \log \left(\prod_{i=1}^n i\right) = \log (n!).$$

But note that the left hand site is actually easier to compute (numerically).

Comment: Do you mean log(n!) at the end?

Comment: @cssk, Oops, I do, thanks!

Comment: Note that you can obtain nice asymptotics for the whole expression by Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 0):

Closed form as such, no. But you can get decent bounds simply by considering (think about the curves and the areas under them sandwiching the staircase representing the sum):

$\begin{align*}
  \int_2^{n + 1} \ln (x - 1) \, d x
     \le \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \ln k
     \le \int_1^{n + 1} \ln x \, d x
\end{align*}$

The integrals are easy to compute.

Refinements are available through the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) (the typical one is [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)), sharp bounds are derived by Robbins "A Remark on Stirling's Formula", AMM 54:10 (oct 1948), pp 987-993.